# Proof by induction that $\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}k^2 = (-1)^{n-1}\frac{(n)(n+1)}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

Through Induction I tried to prove that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}k^2 = (-1)^{n-1}\frac{(n)(n+1)}{2}$$

I first let $n=1$, so that on the left hand side and the right hand side you get 1.
Then I tried to prove that this also works when $$n=n+1$$
So the equation then becomes:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (-1)^{k-1}k^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}k^2 +(-1)^{n-1}\frac{(n)(n+1)}{2}$$
As we know that $\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}k^2 = (-1)^{n-1}\frac{(n)(n+1)}{2}$, we can replace the first term after the $=$ with this. The equation becomes:
$$=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{(n)(n+1)}{2} + (-1)^{n-1}\frac{(n)(n+1)}{2}$$
The I subsitute $n+1$ for $n$, so that:
$$=(-1)^{n+1-1}\frac{(n+1)(n+1+1)}{2} + (-1)^{n+1-1}\frac{(n+1)(n+1+1)}{2}$$
$$=(-1)^{n}\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2} + (-1)^{n}\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$$
$$=(-1)^{n}[\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}+\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}]$$
$$=(-1)^{n}[\frac{(2n^2+6n+4)}{2}]$$
$$=(-1)^{n}[\frac{(2n^2+2n+4n+4)}{2}]$$
$$=(-1)^{n}[\frac{((n+1)(2n+4))}{2}]$$
But how do I proceed from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think it must be
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^{k-1}k^2=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}k^2+(-1)^n(n+1)^2$$
and we get $$(-1)^{n-1} \frac {n(n+1)}{2}+(-1)^n(n+1)^2=(-1)^n\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

If
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k-1} \, k^{2} = (-1)^{n-1} \, \frac{n \, (n+1)}{2} = (-1)^{n-1} \, \binom{n+1}{2}$$
then when $n \to n+1$ it is seen that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (-1)^{k-1}k^2 = \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}k^2 +(-1)^{n}(n+1)^{2}$$
which leads to
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} (-1)^{k-1} \, k^{2} &= \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}k^2 +(-1)^{n}(n+1)^{2} \\
&= (-1)^{n-1} \frac{n (n+1)}{2} + (-1)^{n}(n+1)^{2} \\
&= \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2} \, \left( n^{2} + n - 2 (n^{2} + 2n + 1) \right) \\
&= (-1)^{n} \, \frac{(n+1) \, (n+2)}{2} = (-1)^{n} \binom{n+2}{2}  
\end{align}

Comment: I get that but how can you do that without the binomials?

Comment: One little catch in your solution: when you factored down to $(n+1)(n+2)$ in the final line, there is an extra negative that gets factored out as well, so the $(-1)$ should be raised to the power of $n$ rather than $n-1$. :)